Clarification on the Definition of Bounded Sets in Topological Vector Spaces
In Walter Rudin's "Functional Analysis" book, the definition of a bounded set in a topological space is given as follows:

A subset $E$ of a topological vector space $X$ is said to be bounded if to every neighbourhood $V$ of $0$ in $X$ corresponds a number $s > 0$ such that $E \subset tV$ for every $t > s$.

I'm having difficulty understanding why the condition "for every $t > s$" is necessary in this definition. It seems to me that requiring $E$ to be contained in $tV$ for some $t > s$ would suffice to characterize boundedness

What happens when you try to deduce Rudin's definition (with the $t>s$ part) from your definition (without the $t>s$ part)?

You can look at Theorem 1.14 on balanced neighborhoods of $0$.

See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421134/two-definitions-of-a-bounded-set-in-topological-vector-spaces?rq=1

Now I understand.
